dont send pdf file in telegram bot
I tried to send a pdf file to the bot but it gives the following error: aiogram.exceptions.TelegramBadRequest: Telegram server says - Bad Request: failed to get HTTP URL content
import os
import uuid
import asyncio
from aiogram import Router, F, Bot
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart
from aiogram.types import Message
from gradio_client import Client, handle_file
import requests
start_router = Router()


def question_processing(fileName):
    client = Client("Qwen/Qwen2-Math-Demo")
    result = client.predict(
        image=handle_file(fileName),
        sketchpad={
            "background": handle_file(
                'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gradio-app/gradio/main/test/test_files/bus.png'),
            "layers": [],
            "composite": None
        },
        question="реши, ответ в формате LaTex",
        api_name="/math_chat_bot"
    )
    return result


@start_router.message(CommandStart())
async def cmd_start(message: Message):
    await message.answer("Хай!!!")


@start_router.message(F.photo)
async def send_photo(message: Message, bot: Bot):
    # Generate a unique file name for the downloaded image
    local_filename = f"{uuid.uuid4()}.png"

    # Get the file from the file_id and download it locally
    file_info = await bot.get_file(message.photo[-1].file_id)
    await bot.download_file(file_info.file_path, destination=local_filename)

    await message.answer("Ваш запрос обрабатывается...")

    # Run the blocking function in a separate thread
    result = await asyncio.to_thread(question_processing, local_filename)
    file_name = f"{uuid.uuid4()}.tex"
    f = open(file_name, "w")
    f.write(f"{result}")
    f.close()
    os.system('bash script.sh')
    await message.answer_document("file.pdf")
    os.remove(local_filename)
    os.remove(file_name)
    os.remove("file.tex")



i try function message.answer_document("name_file"), but dont work
